# Ways to protect accessing session directly when it's wrapped as a property?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, session-variables

I have each ASP.NET session variable wrapped in a property with a getter & a setter. Is there a way to make accessing a session variable directly produce an error or a warning during compilation?

I want to 'force' developers, including myself, to access session variables through the wrapper properties instead of directly.

Comment: maybe a `pre-build` script to detect direct access?

Comment: I'm sure there's a way to get [FxCop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429476%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to recognize that.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Resharper, you could add a pattern to its [pattern catalog](http://www.hmemcpy.com/blog/2010/02/resharper-5-hidden-gem-patterns-catalogue/), which can recognize certain patterns as an error. Not only that, but you can also suggest a replacement text that would suggest using a property.

I believe that in your case the search pattern would only need to be something like:

```
Session[$Expression$]
```

Comment: I believe the bigger problem of doing that is that he will need to access the session after in his wrapper properties

Comment: You're right, I guess a way to overcome this would be to use something like session.Contents in the properties (or have R# generate that for you via a live template), but it is kinda lame.